# CSS carousel using transforms with generic x value

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a simple carousel using CSS transforms/transitions. I'm also trying to do this without giving each item in the carousel it's own transform/transition rule

ie: I'd like to have:

```css
 .item.active {
     -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
     -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Instead of  :

```css
 .item1.active {
     -webkit-transform: translate(100px,0);
     -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
 }

 .item2.active {
     -webkit-transform: translate(200px,0);
     -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Demo Here => [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/danwoods/eEwTR/)

I'm starting to feel like this is not possible; anyone done anything similar? Are there style rules besides transforms/transitions I should be using instead?

**Edit**: Doesn't look like this is possible...

Comment: No, you cannot use class selector as a variable to simply make multiples unless you use a preprocessor like SASS or LESS (and mixins).

Comment: But, you can use `:nth-of-type` and `:nth-child` selectors, if that helps you. (I don't know which way your question was pointing).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but I recently created a slideshow that has css3 effects. http://kthornbloom.com/smoothbox.php